# Maximal Unramified Extension of a Subextension

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $L/K$ be a Galois extension (possibly infinite) and $\tilde{K}/K$ be the maximal unramified extension of $K$ in $L$. Let $E/K$ be a subextension of $L/K$. Is it true that the maximal unramified subextension of $E$ inside $L$ is the composite $E \tilde{K}$?

I managed to show that $E \tilde{K}/E$ is unramified and I'm wondering whether it is maximal. If it is not, can I add some properties to the extension $E/K$ to make it maximal?

Comment: Can you clarify what your fields are? For example, are they local fields?

Comment: Oh sorry, what would happen if $L$ and $K$ are separable field extensions of a local field? Or do we need that $L$ and $K$ are finite extensions of a local field?

Comment: If $K$ is a finite extension of $\mathbb Q_p$, then every finite unramified extension is of the form $K(\zeta_{n})$ where $p\nmid n$. That should help you prove your result. (On the other hand, if $K$ is a number field, the result is very false.)

Comment: Should the second sentence say "Is it true that the maximal unramified extension of $E$ in $L$ is the composite $E\tilde K$"? Over a local field I think the claim is true.

Comment: @TokenToucan Yes, I did mean the maximal unramified subextension. Do you maybe have a reference for this?